# grab the value of an element in a different template

Tags: meteor

The code below is trying to grab the username and password from input elements on a template.login and createUser when a button which is in template.footer is clicked.
Being new to javascript and Meteor, my code below probably butchered both.

I thought to make a method call from the footer click event, this call gets the username and password and fires Meteor accounts create and store the returned userId in a local session to be used later. blah..blah..
But how can I get access to input values in one template from another?
so I need your help. Thanks

```js
Template.footer.events({
  'click .myClass': function (event, template) {
    Meteor.call('loginUser', username,password);
  }
});

Meteor.methods({
  //store the useId returned from createUser in a local session userId
  loginUser: function (username, password) {
    Accounts.createUser(username, password, function () {
      Session.set(userId, this.value);
    });
  }
});
```

```html
<template name="footer">
  <footer>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-bottom">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
          {{#each footerButtons}}
            <h2>
              <button class="col-xs-{{footerButtonsScaling}} myClass" type="button">{{text.toUpperCase}}</button>
            </h2>
          {{/each}}
        </div>
      </div>
    </nav>
  </footer>
</template>

<template name="login">
  <form action="">
    <input type="text" name="username" placeholder="type your ID" value="{{username}}">
    <input type="password" name="password" placeholder="type your PIN" value="{{password}}">
  </form>
</template>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just use jQuery to access field values anywhere in the DOM:

```
var username = $('[name="username"]').val();
var password = $('[name="password"]').val();
```